# Find duplicates in mySQL but with a specific status

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an orders table and I need to find the duplicates - orders which have the same dd_number and dd_code, BUT one of the orders must have the status of "checkout_completed".

The following is my current SQL which correctly finds duplicate orders which have the same dd_number and dd_code, however I cant work out how to check for the status:

```
SELECT
            tbOrders.id, tbOrders.dd_number, tbOrders.dd_code, tbOrders.status, COUNT(*) AS totalDupes
        FROM
            tbOrders
        WHERE 
            dd_number IS NOT NULL 
        AND
            dd_number != ''
        AND
            dd_number != '000000'
        AND
            dd_number != '00000000'
        GROUP BY
            dd_number, dd_code
        HAVING totalDupes > 1
```

Adding a WHERE clause of status = 'checkout_complete' does not work as it requires both orders to have the same status. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `id` and `status` are not in aggregate function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
        tbOrders.id, tbOrders.dd_number, tbOrders.dd_code, tbOrders.status, COUNT(*) AS totalDupes,
SUM(CASE WHEN status='checkout_complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as status_count
    FROM
        tbOrders
    WHERE 
        dd_number IS NOT NULL 
    AND
        dd_number != ''
    AND
        dd_number != '000000'
    AND
        dd_number != '00000000'
    GROUP BY
        dd_number, dd_code
    HAVING totalDupes > 1 and status_count=1
```

You can introduce one more aggregate field counting records with the status

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Mmm, multiple way of doing it. I'd suggest using the `HAVING` clause with conditional aggregation :

```
HAVING totalDupes > 1
   AND MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'checkout_complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

Though your query seems wrong. If `ID` is unique, then a random `ID` will be choosen , same goes for `STATUS` . All the columns should either be in the `GROUP BY` or wrapped with an aggregation function. Note that only MySQL older versions accept your syntax. In any other RDBMS this will throw an error.